# Renaming namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias

I've been doing C++ for a long time now but I just faced a question this morning to which I couldn't give an answer: "Is it possible to create aliases for namespaces in C++ ?"

Let me give an example. Let's say I had the following header:

```
namespace old
{
  class SomeClass {};
}
```

Which, for unspecified reasons had to become:

```
namespace _new
{
  namespace nested
  {
    class SomeClass {}; // SomeClass hasn't changed
  }
}
```

Now if I have an old code base which refers to `SomeClass`, I can quickly (and dirtily) "fix" the change by adding:

```
namespace old
{
  typedef _new::nested::SomeClass SomeClass;
}
```

But is there a way to import **everything** from `_new::nested` into `old` without having to `typedef` explicitely every type ?

Something similar to Python `import * from ...`.

Thank you.

Comment: `new` is maybe a bad example for a namespace name. ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
using namespace new::nested;
```

[Example at Ideone](http://ideone.com/FiA0g).

Or if you actually want a real alias:

```
namespace on = one::nested;
```

[Example at Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ss5FF).

Comment: The second one is much better than the first one... the first one does not create an alias, but rather brings the symbols from the other namespace and that might end up in name clashes or unwanted results (if a function overload in the `nested` namespace is a better match than an overload in the current namespace, it will suddenly change its pick)

Comment: @David: Yes, but it seems to solve the problem the OP seems to have. :)

Answer (score 34):

This:

```
namespace old = newns::nested;
```

would seem to be what you want.