# Is it possible to make a re-definable namespace alias in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, alias

I would like to create a namespace alias that can be changed globally to refer to different scopes at runtime.  Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace scopePrimary {
    int somethingOfInterest = 1;
}
namespace scopeSecondary {
    int somethingOfInterest = 2;
}
namespace scopeTarget = scopePrimary;

int doStuffInTargetScope() {
    using namespace scopeTarget;
    return somethingOfInterest;
}

int main() {
    // Do something with the somethingOfInterest variable defined in scopePrimary
    std::cout << "doStuffInTargetScope():\n" \
    "  somethingOfInterest = " << doStuffInTargetScope() << std::endl;

    namespace scopeTarget = scopeSecondary;
    using namespace scopeTarget;

    // Do something with the somethingOfInterest variable defined in scopeSecondary
    std::cout << "doStuffInTargetScope():\n" \
    "  somethingOfInterest = " << doStuffInTargetScope() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "main():\n  somethingOfInterest = "
    << somethingOfInterest << std::endl;
}
```

Now, the above code does compile, but instead of getting the output would I expect:

```
doStuffInTargetScope():
  somethingOfInterest = 1
doStuffInTargetScope():
  somethingOfInterest = 2
main():
  somethingOfInterest = 2
```

I'm getting this output:

```
doStuffInTargetScope():
  somethingOfInterest = 1
doStuffInTargetScope():
  somethingOfInterest = 1
main():
  somethingOfInterest = 2
```

It seems that when trying to redefine `namespace scopeTarget`, C++ will only use the most local alias definition, instead of overwriting the global alias. 
 Does anyone know a work-around to achieve my goal here?

Comment: No you can't. Use function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change namespaces at run time. Function pointers would achieve the desired effect.

For namespaces see: [Renaming namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108704/renaming-namespaces)

For function pointers I found this useful: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/

Comment: That is a really awful site. Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282) instead.